# jQuery Validations issue in dialog form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-dialog

I've login form as shown below,

```
<a href="#" id="loginLink">click Here to Log in</a>
<div class="formDiv" id="formDiv">
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="#">
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br/>
    <label>Passw</label><input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="loginbtn" name="loginbtn">
</form>
</div>
```

I'm showing above form to users using `jQuery Dialog`,if form without dialog box(i,e normal HTML) then validations are doing without any issue its [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNMfA/10/) but if I'm showing form in dialog box then validations are not doing its [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNMfA/11/), may I know the reason behind this ?

Comment: Off-topic:  _"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — **in the question itself**. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) for guidance."_  ~ Where is all of your jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

TRy http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/WNMfA/12/

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("a#loginLink").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $(".formDiv").dialog({
            closeOnEscape: false,
            title:"Login Form",
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width:'350px',
            position:'fixed',

            close:function()
            {                    
                $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
            }
        });  
});
```

Use  $(".formDiv") dont recreate it inside open function.

Answer (score 1):

You have several major flaws...

1)  Your code that calls `.validate()`...

```
$(document).on("click", '#loginbtn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#loginForm").validate();        
    alert('test');  
    //I want to do Ajax stuff   
});
```

Do not call `.validate()` within a `click` handler because it only needs to be called one time.  The `.validate()` method is not the method for calling validation on the form.  It is only the method for *initializing* the plugin on the form.  So just like in your working example, you must call `.validate()` as soon as the form is constructed, which is normally within the DOM ready event.  The entire `on('click')` handler function above can be removed.

2)  Your code that opens the dialog...

```
open:function(){                   
    $(this).html($("#formDiv").html());
},
```

Within your `open` callback, you duplicate the HTML from a hidden `div` into your `dialog` `div` for the form.  The main problem with this technique is that you now have more than one element on the same page with with same `id`.  Not only is this invalid HTML, but the jQuery Validate plugin will only apply to the first instance, the original hidden instance, of this `id`.  Remove the `open` callback and attach the hidden `div` to `.dialog()` like this:  `$("#formDiv").dialog( ...`

3)  Your comment indicates you want to submit this form with `ajax()`.  If that's the case, use the `submitHandler` callback function of the jQuery Validate plugin.  [As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/), this is the *"right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated."*

```
$("#loginForm").validate({ // initialize the plugin
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        // your ajax here;               // submit the data
        $("#formDiv").dialog("close");   // close the dialog
        alert('submitted with ajax');    // for demo 
        return false;                    // prevent regular form submit action
    }
});
```

---

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/TRHxZ/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#loginForm").validate({ // initialize the plugin
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // your ajax here;               // submit the data
            $("#formDiv").dialog("close");   // close the dialog
            return false;                    // prevent regular form submit action
        }
    });

    $("a#loginLink").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#formDiv").dialog({
            closeOnEscape: false,
            title: "Login Form",
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: '350px',
            position: 'fixed',
            close: function () {
                $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: You have said my question is offtopic,after 1 hour you have given a lengthy answer though the previous answers described the same briefly,anyhow thanks for your effort in answering my offtopic question.

Comment: @Mahesh.D, it's simply off-topic for not showing full code in the question.  Copy your jQuery code from your jsFiddle into your OP and it will be on-topic.